# What's the difference between .Xresources and .Xdefaults?

Tags: xorg, configuration

How are these two files connected to xrdb?  Should I have both, or just one in my home directory?  Do lines like these go in either file?

```
XTerm*background: white

URxvt.font: xft:Monospace
```

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/243914/xresources-or-xdefaults pretty much answers this.

Answer (score 2):

*Xresources* is a user-level configuration dotfile, typically located at `~/.Xresources`

Using `~/.Xdefaults` is deprecated, so this article will only refer to resources loaded with `xrdb`